# Plot two sets of data in one BarChart

Tags: charts

I have two sets data as following:

```
data1 = 
  {11, 11, 24, 19, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 16, 15, 16, 16, 19, 23, 36,
   12, 11, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 11, 13, 13, 18};

data2 = 
  {15, 10, 13, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7, 11, 26, 4, 4, 7, 5, 
   6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5};
```

I want to put them together, like in this example picture.

[image]

Compare two sets of data, (ignore Lables in this picture).

It seems that the `Stacked` option doesn't work well.

Comment: Have you tried `Show[BarChart[data1, ChartStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7]]], 
 BarChart[data2, ChartStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.7]]]]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to using `Show` as suggested by rotom407, which would give a chart looking like

```
Show[
 BarChart[data1, ChartStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.75]]], 
 BarChart[data2, ChartStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5]]]]
```

[image: show]

I think you should consider two other charting styles, both of which have the advantages of better color and showing all bars fully.

Transposed stacking

```
BarChart[Transpose[{data1, data2}], 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image: stack]

Paired with common x-axis

```
PairedBarChart[Style[data1, Red], Style[data2, Blue], BarOrigin -> "XAxis"]
```

[image: paired]

#### Update

This update addresses the question raised by OP in a comment below which concerns adding a legend to the paired bar chart.

`ChartLegends` doesn't permit the user to specify colors for the legend swatches, so I suggest using `Legended`.

```
PairedBarChart[
  Legended[Style[data1, Red], "data1"],
  Legended[Style[data2, Blue], "data2"],
  BarOrigin -> "XAxis"]
```

legened[image]

Comment: BTW, how to add the ChartLegends as example picture. When I use ChartLegends -> {"data1", "data2"}, the color pieces always yellow.

Comment: @WangShen. Which of the kinds of chart I discussed  in this answer are you using?

Comment: The 3rd chart, PairedBarChart.

Comment: For the legend, one can also use `ChartLegends -> 
 SwatchLegend[{color1,color2}, {"label1", "label2"}]`

Answer (score 2):

Actually I suspect that you should be using `Histogram` not `BarChart`.The image you have posted is a histogram. The simplest implementation is

```
Histogram[{data1, data2}]
```

however your example data sets are likely to be the bin counts rather than the raw data. From the docs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PairedBarChart[data1, data2, BarOrigin -> "XAxis", 
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Blue}, None, None}, 
 ChartLegends -> {{"data1", "data2"}, None, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]